# How to idiomatically iterate one half of an array and modify the structure of the other?

Tags: rust, idioms

What is the idiomatic way to iterate (read) over the first half of the vector and change the structure of the second half of the vector depending on the first? This is very abstract but some algorithms could be boiled down to this problem. I want to write this simplified C++ example in Rust:

```cpp
for (var i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1 ; j < vec.length; j++) {
        if (f(vec[i], vec[j])) {
            vec.splice(j, 1);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for an idiomatic approach that does the same thing as the example? You don't seem to provide a clear problem other than that. And by the way,  I would advise you to keep irrelevant comments out of the question in the future.

Comment: I want to read one part of the array and the same time structurally modify the other part of the array.  So in any given moment 0..k part of the array remain unmodified but the k..len could be arbitrarily rebuilt(for example in a random way). I cannot give a clear real-world example. But I have an intuition that such problems may arouse. So let's be as generic as possible. And most importantly this problem without the borrow checker has a clear solution in C-like languages

Comment: The problem is that you should not make it too generic without understanding its implications to the question. In particular, do you want to be able to add and remove elements from the vector? That makes the problem much more difficult. We might really be more helpful to you if you narrow it down to a specific problem.

Comment: You are right that the question is unclear and isn't well thought out. @red75prime put some effort to answer the question. I think in the scope of this question it would be fair to stick just to the simple question. Thank you, answering and commenting. I'll try to came up with a more elaborate question. By the way, entirely rebuilding with removal and perhaps addition to the second part of the array is what I meant.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to accept answer randomly, @red75prime had do a mistake by answer you. Unclear question should not be answer. This will be better if you [edit] your question to something more clear because this question is not useful in SO and should be close as unclear.

Comment: @Stargateur, It could be useful to remember that in rare cases you can't do better than go full C. I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An idiomatic solution of this generic problem will be the same for Rust and C, as there's no constraints which would allow simplification.

We need to use indexes because vector reallocation will invalidate the references contained by the iterators. We need to compare the index against the current length of the vector on each cycle because the length could be changed. Thus an idiomatic solution will look like this:

```
let mut i = 0;
while i < v.len() {
    let mut j = i + 1;
    while j < v.len() {
        if f(v[i], v[j]) {
            v.splice(j, 1);
        } else {
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    i += 1;
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e95f911d931e1b5bbfdd312208922b23&version=stable&backtrace=0)

While this code covers the general case, it is rarely useful. It doesn't capture specifics, which are usually inherent to the problem at hand. In turn, the compiler is unable to catch any errors at compile time. I don't advise writing something like this without considering another approaches first.

Comment: This is not really idiomatic. At least the first `while` loop can be replaced by a `for` loop over a range: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=081a39fcadd677664f14a939e69f91a3&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @PeterHall, range is fine for this specific instance of a problem, but it requires assumption that outer loop doesn't access `v[i]`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3e12a336894900d1c819f0e9a2f0866e&version=stable&backtrace=0